# Do any other languages support Typescript's mapped types and conditional types features?

Tags: typescript

I've been working with Typescript's type mapping and conditional typing features and finding them to be really unique and groundbreaking in terms of building developer-friendly APIs for my code. I get the impression they're fairly unique features, but thought I'd ask whether there are any other languages out there with feature equivalence? Or is Typescript the only one?

Comment: Please see docs for Scala 3 https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/new-in-scala3.html . They have added union, intersections and other interesting types. Also I think Rust have pretty interesting type system, yet both of them don't have conditional and mapped types

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript's type system, with its powerful mapped and conditional types, is indeed one of the most advanced among statically-typed languages.

However, TypeScript isn't the only language with advanced type system features. While the exact syntax and behavior may differ, several other languages offer expressive type systems with capabilities that can achieve similar outcomes.

**Scala** type system is extremely rich. Features like type classes, path-dependent types, and implicit conversions provide for very expressive type-level programming. Scala 3 introduced even more advanced features, such as dependent function types and match types, which are reminiscent of TypeScript's conditional types.

```
type Elem[X] = X match {
case List[t] => tcase Array[t] => t
}

def firstElement[X](xs: X)(using ev: X <:< Iterable[Elem[X]]): Elem[X] = xs.head
```

**Haskell** is a pure functional language with a strong and expressive type system. Type classes in Haskell are a way to define operations that can work over a variety of types. Haskell also has features like GADTs (Generalized Algebraic Data Types) and type families, which allow for advanced type-level computations.

```
class Printable a where
  toString :: a -> String
instance Printable Int where
  toString = show

instance Printable Bool where
  toString = show
```

**Idris** is a general-purpose functional programming language with dependent types. This means that types can be dependent on values, which allows for incredibly expressive typing. This is a step beyond most other type systems in mainstream languages.

```
data Vect : Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Nil : Vect 0 a
  (::) : (x : a) -> (xs : Vect n a) -> Vect (n + 1) a
```

**Kotlin**, while less expressive than Scala in terms of its type system, does have features like sealed classes, extension functions, and type-safe builders that make it a pleasure to create developer-friendly APIs.

```
sealed class Result<out T, out E>
data class Success<T>(val value: T) : Result<T, Nothing>()
data class Error<E>(val error: E) : Result<Nothing, E>()
```

**Rust**'s type system, while different in its goals (focused on memory safety), is still quite expressive. Traits and associated types in Rust can be used to create flexible and type-safe abstractions.

```
trait Iterator {
    type Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
}

struct Counter;
impl Iterator for Counter {
    type Item = u32;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<u32> {
        // ... implementation ...
    }
}
```

**Swift**'s protocol-oriented design and its generics support also lend themselves to creating expressive type-safe APIs. Features like associated types and protocol extensions can be used to create flexible abstractions.

```
protocol Container {
    associatedtype ItemType
    mutating func append(_ item: ItemType)
    var count: Int { get }
    subscript(i: Int) -> ItemType { get }
}
```

**F#**, has an expressive type system with features like type providers, which allow you to generate types on-the-fly based on external data sources.

```
type dbSchema = SqlDataProvider<"""Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;""">

let db = dbSchema.GetDataContext()

let firstCustomerName = query {
    for customer in db.Customers do
    select customer.Name
    head
}
```